# JS completely stopped loading but Files are found

Tags: php, jquery

Basically I've enqueued all of the files I need and can see there been picked up in the browser but for some reason none of them seem to load or function correctly and I get no errors in the console.

I'm a complete novice with jquery so go easy on me please.

website with the issue http://www.sportsrule.co.uk/

here is my functions.php file that calls the js

```
<?php

/* configuration */
require TEMPLATEPATH . '/configs/common.php';
require TEMPLATEPATH . '/configs/custom.php';
require TEMPLATEPATH . '/configs/posttype.php';
require TEMPLATEPATH . '/configs/ajax.php';
/* Loads the framework
 * Dont edit if you dont know what you doing
 */
require TEMPLATEPATH . '/wpld-master/wpld-master.php';
require TEMPLATEPATH . '/configs/metabox.php';
/**
 * Slightly Modified Options Framework
 */
require_once ('admin/index.php');

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

function my_add_javascript() {
        wp_enqueue_script(
                'quicksand',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.quicksand.js',
                array( 'jquery' ),
        true
        );
        wp_enqueue_script(
        'easing',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jquery.easing.1.3.js',
                array( 'jquery' ),
        true
        );
         wp_enqueue_script(
        'easing',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/easySlider1.7.7.js',
                array( 'jquery' ),
        true
        );
          wp_enqueue_script(
        'easing',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/query.nivo.slider.pack.js',
                array( 'jquery' ),
        true
        );
         wp_enqueue_script(
        'easing',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/script.js',
                array( 'jquery' ),
        true
        );
          wp_enqueue_script(
        'easing',
                get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/jcarousellite.js',
                array( 'jquery' ),
        true
        );

}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_add_javascript' );
```

here is my footer.php which is where i run the scripts

```
  <?php global $data; ?>



</div>
<!-- end content -->
<!-- footer -->
<div id="footer">
    <div class="footer-widget floatleft">  
        <?php if (!function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Footer Widget")) : ?>


            <div class="widget">
                <h3>Company</h3>
                <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employe dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression.</p>
                <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les annees 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour realiser un livre specimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siecles.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="widget">
                <h3>Services</h3>
                <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employe dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression.</p>
                <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les annees 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour realiser un livre specimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siecles.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="widget last">
                <h3>Recruitment</h3>
                <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employe dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression.</p>
                <p>Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les annees 1500, quand un peintre anonyme assembla ensemble des morceaux de texte pour realiser un livre specimen de polices de texte. Il n'a pas fait que survivre cinq siecles.</p>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!-- end footer -->
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="bottom-logos" class="clearfix">
    <ul class="clearfix">
        <li><a href="http://www.therulegroup.co.uk/" title="the rules group"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(623,'full' ) ; ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.translationsrule.co.uk/" title="translation rule"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(628,'full' ) ; ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.sportsrule.co.uk/" title="translation rule"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(632,'full' ) ; ?></a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.sportsrule.co.uk/recruitment/" title="translation rule"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(633,'full' ) ; ?></a></li>


        <li class="floatright"><a href="http://www.sportsrule.co.uk/about-us/" title="linked"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(626,'full' ) ; ?></a></li>

        <li class="floatright" style="margin-right:10px;" >

<a href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Sportsrule/113349598693860" title="twitter"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(762,'full' ) ; ?></a></li>

<li style="margin-left:31px"><a href="http://twitter.com/Sportsrulecouk" title="twitter"><?php echo wp_get_attachment_image(761,'full' ) ; ?></a></li>



    </ul>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<!-- bottom -->
<div id="bottom">
    <p class="floatleft">Sportsrule Ltd ©  |  Company No. 813 3689  |  +44 (0) 1482 228831  |  <a href="">info@sportsrule.co.uk</a> </p>
    <p class="floatright"><a title="web design hull" href="http://www.getextra.co.uk" target="_blank">
<span style="color: #ff6600;">Get</span>
<strong><span style="color: #808080; margin-left: -3px;">extra</span></strong>
<span style="color: #808080;"> - </span></a>
<span style="color: #808080;">
       <a title="web design hull" href="http://www.getextra.co.uk" target="_blank">web design hull</a>
</span></p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<!-- end bottom -->
</div>
<!-- end container -->
<!-- javascript -->

<?php if (!is_home() || !is_front_page()) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            // Clone portfolio items to get a second collection for Quicksand plugin
            var $portfolioClone = $(".portfolio").clone();
            // Attempt to call Quicksand on every click event handler
            $(".filter a").click(function(e){

                $(".filter li").removeClass("current");

                // Get the class attribute value of the clicked link
                var $filterClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");

                if ( $filterClass == "all" ) {
                    var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li");
                } else {
                    var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li[data-type~=" + $filterClass + "]");
                }

                // Call quicksand
                $(".portfolio").quicksand( $filteredPortfolio, {
                    duration: 800,
                    easing: 'easeInOutQuad'
                }, function(){

                    //Blur newly cloned portfolio items on mouse over and apply prettyPhoto
                    /*
                    $(".portfolio li").hover(function(){
                        $(this).children('.title').addClass('hover');
                        $(this).children('.desc').slideDown('slow');
                    }, function() {
                        $(this).children('.title').removeClass('hover');
                        $(this).children('.desc').slideUp('slow');
                    });
                    */
                });


                $(this).parent().addClass("current");

                // Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>


<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
      auto: 800,
    speed: 1500,
    });
});

    </script>
<?php } ?>
<!-- end javascript -->
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                var gaJsHost = (("https:" == document.location.protocol) ? "https://ssl." : "http://www.");
                document.write(unescape("%3Cscript src='" + gaJsHost + "google-analytics.com/ga.js' type='text/javascript'%3E%3C/script%3E"));
                </script>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                try{
                var pageTracker = _gat._getTracker("UA-16453215-1");
                pageTracker._trackPageview();
                } catch(err) {}
                </script>

<?php include_once('/home/sites/sportsrule.co.uk/public_html/wp-content/plugins/theme-inc.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Default value for `in_footer` param is false, so your scripts will be included in header. Do you use `wp_head()` in your header?

Comment: Yeah I do, the scripts all seem to load fine the website that is effected is http://goo.gl/rRdDP forgot to mention

Comment: Could you describe _specific_ JS features that are failing? Your site loads, links work. What is _not_ working, so we don't have to guess?

Comment: Its the quicksand.js on the news page and the homepage sliders using jquerycarousel and nivoslider.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're testing if it's NOT the home page (your news page) before outputting your block of javascript, so your quicksand code never gets output to page:

```
if (!is_home() || !is_front_page()) {
```

I don't see any code anywhere that creates the nivo slider.

This block needs to reference jQuery, not $:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
      auto: 800,
    speed: 1500,
    });
});
```

should be:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $(".anyClass").jCarouselLite({
      auto: 800,
    speed: 1500,
    });
});
```

Comment: This has fixed one Piece of code, the quicksand.js however is ment to do the same effects as it does on the buttons on the testimonials page and case studies

Comment: The script.js file pulls it in I think but I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: I understand what the quicksand code does, however as I said your block of code is not being output to the page which is why nothing is happening. despite the name, `is_home` tests if it's your posts page, which I assume is your news page.

Comment: Yeah this is correct milo, so what would I do to fix this sorry for the late response.

Comment: if you want it on your home page, assuming your news page is the page you've set as the page for posts in settings > reading, then remove `!is_home()`, so it would be `if (!is_front_page()) {`

Comment: When I set the news page in settings > reading I get completely the wrong page when I click on the link. I've also tried is_home() && !is_front_page() and this doesn't work either.

Comment: accepting your awnser as it fixed multiple problems and gave me a better understanding -> solved by deleting the conditional completey

Answer (score 0):

You got the same handle `easing` for a couple of Js files. That could explain the error. Handle are used (for example) by minifier.

**EDIT:**

```
 wp_enqueue_script('easing1', /*...etc*/);
 wp_enqueue_script('easing2', /*...etc*/);
 wp_enqueue_script('easing3', /*...etc*/);
```

**EDIT 2:** you do not enqueue the script the correct way, it's :

```
<?php wp_enqueue_script( $handle, $src, $deps, $ver, $in_footer ); ?>
```

So add a version number or write `null` in fourth position.

Comment: I have no idea, which handlers are the same. Do you mean the things that trigger the jquery.

Comment: I've edited my answer hope this will fix your problem.

Comment: After changing these I've got 3 more errors now.

Comment: I've edited code to show you how to enqueue your scripts, there's a little error in your code