# Javascript not loading on certain page

Tags: php, jquery

My Javascript doesn't seem to get called on this page called news, this uses the default post custom type in wordpress.

Every other page that uses's this javascript is a custom post type I've implemented, I've got an idea of what's causing it and thats the if conditional at the top, but I've tried removing !is_home and it still doesn't load the js on the page.

```
<?php if (!is_home() || !is_front_page()) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            // Clone portfolio items to get a second collection for Quicksand plugin
            var $portfolioClone = $(".portfolio").clone();
            // Attempt to call Quicksand on every click event handler
            $(".filter a").click(function(e){

                $(".filter li").removeClass("current"); 

                // Get the class attribute value of the clicked link
                var $filterClass = $(this).parent().attr("class");

                if ( $filterClass == "all" ) {
                    var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li");
                } else {
                    var $filteredPortfolio = $portfolioClone.find("li[data-type~=" + $filterClass + "]");
                }

                // Call quicksand
                $(".portfolio").quicksand( $filteredPortfolio, { 
                    duration: 800, 
                    easing: 'easeInOutQuad' 
                }, function(){

                    //Blur newly cloned portfolio items on mouse over and apply prettyPhoto
                    /*
                    $(".portfolio li").hover(function(){
                        $(this).children('.title').addClass('hover');
                        $(this).children('.desc').slideDown('slow');
                    }, function() {
                        $(this).children('.title').removeClass('hover');
                        $(this).children('.desc').slideUp('slow');
                    });
                    */
                });


                $(this).parent().addClass("current");

                // Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
                e.preventDefault();
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/106277/4771).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like it is your `if` statement possibly. It's kind of tricky to say "if it's not this or if it's not that, then I want this to happen".

Normally you have to negate *and* change the operator. Try

`<?php if (!is_home() && !is_front_page()) { ?>`

This says "I want this to run on every single page that is not home or front page"

Comment: I've tried this and it doesn't seem to work either, it uses the default post type

Comment: removed it compeltely and it works.

Answer (score 0):

if you set the page template loading the posts as the blog landing page then it probably isnt passing the second param of your if statement, [see is_front_page()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_front_page) in WP Codex